# How to reduce the file upload time in Web Server for large files like 1GB in java

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, file-upload, arrays

I have tried by reading the file in a byte array and splitting them into parts before uploading to the server. I merge all the parts finally.

**Drawbacks i faced is:**

1.File size is shrinking or increasing randomly

2.Since i split a single file into 5 parts 5 times the request has been submitted

3.Rather than increasing the server upload time. it slowed down the already existing server upload time.

***Is there any other way instead of this.***?

Comment: Did you think of some kind of compression? zip? gzip? What are your endpoints? Is it a spring app uploading the data to another spring app or to a apache instance?

Comment: @gregor: yes its a spring app uploading data to the web server, if i try compressing the files before uploading what kind impact that will do in server uploading time ?

Comment: It depends ... More if you upload uncompressed data like text or xml files, or less if we speak of already compressed data like jpeg images or mpeg movies.